# http://localhost/phpmyadmin doesn't work

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, lamp

So, this is my problem. I have installed phpmyadmin via

```
sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin.
```

When I try to go "localhost/phpmyadmin", it downloads a file, called "download", without any explanation.

P.S. I have already installed LAMP before phpmyadmin.

Comment: this belongs on [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/)

Comment: did you run phpmyadmin?

Comment: Have you tried restarting apache? PHP module might be installed but not loaded.

Comment: @Theolodis What do you mean?

Comment: @pauk960 I restarted it several times. In fact, I've even reconfigured phpmyadmin and mysql.

Comment: Have you restarted the whole system, Just try restarting your system same thing happened to me yesterday. @user1499804

Comment: What’s inside the `download` file, when you try to open it in an editor?

Answer (score 3):

Add the following line to /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

```
Include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf
```

Or the path that is correct for your system. After restart apache.

Comment: This doesn't help. I made this before.

Comment: Using any htaccess files?

Comment: Shouldn't this step should be handled automatically by the package manager?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem. It was very noobian mistake.

I really forgot, that I was using suPHP instead the original PHP5. Now, I removed suPHP mode and enabled PHP5  and everything is working.

Answer (score 1):

At my site, the dashboard of phpmyadmin didn't show up, but the php file that
would show up the dashboard. This was because, 
I forgot to install the connection between apache and php:

apt-get install libapache2-mod-php

After doing it, it worked.